# Is it possible in XPATH to find an element by attribute value, not by name?

Tags: xpath

For example I have an XML element:

```html
<input id="optSmsCode" type="tel" name="otp" placeholder="SMS-code">
```

Suppose I know that somewhere there must be an attribute with `otp` value, but I don’t know in what attribute it can be, respectively, is it possible to have an XPath expression of type like this:

```
.//input[(contains(*, "otp")) or (contains(*, "ode"))]
```

Comment: Could you specify whether "otp" and "ode" are expected to be the (whole) value of an attribute, or just a substring of the value? In the former case, using contains() may incorrectly select some elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this and see if it works:

```
one = '//input/@*[(contains(.,"otp") or contains(.,"ode"))]/..'
print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(one))
```

Edit:

The `contains()` function has a required cardinality of first argument of either one or zero. In plain(ish) English, it means you can check only one element at a time to see if it contains the target string.

So, the expression above goes through each attribute of `input` separately (`/@*`), checks if the attribute value of that specific attribute contains within it the target string and - if target is found - goes up to the parent of that attribute (`/..`) which, in the case of an attribute, is the node itself (`input`).

Comment: It looks like it works, but can you please explain what's going on here?

Comment: sorry, but can I add ```not contains``` somehow? This does not work: ```.//input/@*[(contains(., "otp") or contains(., "ode") or contains(., "assword") or contains(., "numeric")) and not(contains(., "hidden"))]/..```

Comment: @IvanYakushenko It's possible, but not the way you tried it. In any event, you should probably post it as a separate question, per SO policy. I'll be happy to take a look (and so would others as well).

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression selects all `<input>` elements that have some attribute, whose string value contains "otp" or "ode". **Notice** that there is no need to "go up to the parent ..."     [image]

```
//input[@*[contains(., 'otp') or contains(., 'ode')]]
```

**If we know that "otp" or "ode" must be the whole value of the attribute (not just a substring of the value), then this expression is stricter and more efficient to evaluate**:

```
//input[@*[. ='otp' or . = 'ode']]
```

In this latter case ("otp" or "ode" are the whole value of the attribute), if we have to compare against many values then an XPath expression of the above form will quickly become too long. There is a way to simplify such long expression and do just a single comparison:

```
//input[@*[contains('|s1|s2|s3|s4|s5|', concat('|', ., '|'))]]
```

The above expression selects all `input` elements in the document, that have at least one attribute whose value is one of the strings `"s1"`, `"s2"`, `"s3"`, `"s4"` or `"s5"`.